# Actual usage of WS-CDL

Tags: web-services, architecture

I've not been able to wrap my head around the usage of WS-CDL. It is not an executable language, unlike BPEL. So, how is it actually used?

Searching *teh* googles (*all hail teh google*) doesn't really yield anything tangible, only examples of WS-CDL describing very simple interactions. I don't find references of tooling or engines that operate on WS-CDL.

If one were to do the same search on BPEL and service orchestration, then we get something, we get concrete examples and enginees/tooling.  Plus, service orchestration is very concrete. One doesn't have to refer to the WS-* standards to see orchestration in real life. This is the only type of externally defined service composition I've seen in real life (WS-* based and otherwise.)

So, I'm asking this question out of genuine curiosity: what are the actual use case scenarios of WS-CDL? What are your experiences (the good, the bad and the ugly) with WS-CDL?

====== EDIT 7/2/2012 ======

To follow up the answer I accepted (thanks user1496147), I found the following paper (linked from an orchestration vs choreography [blog post](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnreynolds/archive/2006/01/service_orchest.html)):

[Barros, Dumas & Oak "A Critical Overview of WS-CDL", BPTrends, March 2005](http://www.java.net/external?url=http://www.bptrends.com/publicationfiles/03-05%20WP%20WS-CDL%20Barros%20et%20al.pdfhttp://www.java.net/external?url=http://www.bptrends.com/publicationfiles/03-05%20WP%20WS-CDL%20Barros%20et%20al.pdf)

The interesting thing to note is the following passage in its concluding remarks:

> Ultimately, it may be that the WS-CDL standardization effort came too
>   early in the evolution of SOAs. Indeed, WS-CDL has attempted at the
>   same time to be groundbreaking and to create a consensus. In this
>   respect, it is insightful to compare the development of WS-CDL with
>   that of BPEL. BPEL stemmed from two sources, WSFL and XLang, which
>   derived themselves from languages supported by existing tools (namely
>   MQSeries Workflow and BizTalk). Furthermore, together with the first
>   draft of BPEL, a prototype implementation was released. In contrast,
>   WS-CDL has been developed without any prior implementation  and does
>   not derive (directly) from any language supported by an
>   implementation.

The lack of tooling was my first cue about the state of WS-CDL, and would explain (partially at least) how WS-CDL ended up belly up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, its not an executable language - it is a design (or architectural) artifact for specifying the interactions that occur between distributed participants. Think of it as a high level blueprint of your SOA, rather than something that gets executed.

How it is used?

As with any design artifact it can be used to guide the development of your implementation, and even generate the initial template for your services. However it can also be used for testing/verification purposes to ensure that the implemented system actually conforms to the choreography, as you have a machine readable description of how your business transactions should execute across your distributed system.

The reason you don't find much when you do a google search is that the recommendation (w3c term) never gained any adoption amongst vendors.

Apart from the lack of vendor support, it also has two further limitations, one being that it does not have a graphical grammer, and secondly it does not have a compatible endpoint (behavioural) description, which would make it easier to understand the mapping between the global behaviour (choreography) and the behaviour of each service endpoint. If the WS-CDL and WS-BPEL communities had been able to work together (one being W3C and the other OASIS), then maybe this could have been addressed.

However the good news is that BPMN2 has introduced a choreography model, which is compatible with the BPMN2 process model, as well as having its own graphical grammer.

Tool support for BPMN2 choreography is in the early stages. There is a BPMN2 modeller at Eclipse that supports the choreography model, and I am working on tools to use choreography to help generate artifacts, and validate the runtime execution of a distributed system here: http://www.jboss.org/savara

Hope that helps.

Comment: It has certainly clarified things. Thank you.